# Draw line on Y-axis as shown in attached figure, on existing X-Y plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have X-Y data which I plotted using matplotlib, I want to draw a line on Y axis at known X-coordinate, something like in attached figure. What will be the best (smartest) way to do that?

[test_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfPCF.jpg)

My code using matplotlib would be the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
year = [1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010]
sample = [45.91, 20.09, 98.07, 107.7, 158.5, 70.6]
plt.plot(year, sample, color='red')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Sample')
plt.title('Sample graph')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: To determine the best way to do this we need to see the code you have already written.

Comment: I just plotted using X,Y and not a line yet. I don't know how to do it so I posted to get some suggestions.

Comment: So you want a vertical line only?

Comment: Yeah, intersecting existing X-Y plot.https://imgur.com/a/9d7mKAb

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for I believe is the axvline or axhline methods for a matplotlib figure.

Docs : https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html

```
plt.axvline(x_value, ymin=0, ymax=1)
```

Use `ymax` to fit the top of the line to your data if desired (normalized between 0 and 1). Something like `ymax=lineMax/plt.gca().get_ylim()[1]`